# IndexError in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, error-handling

I was trying to write a function that accepts a list of integers as the parameter and then returns the list back with only positive integers (in the same order they were before) but I keep getting an index error.

```
def filter_positive_list(raw_data):
    le=len(raw_data)
    for i in range(le):
        if raw_data[i]<0:
            raw_data.pop(i)
        else:
            pass
data = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
filter_positive_list(data)
print(data)
```

Comment: run for loop as `for i in range(le-1, -1, -1):`..

Comment: By the time you get to the end of your loop, your list is shorter because you have removed some elements, so your loop runs off the end of the list.

Comment: @cherishroby 
You can simply use filter method to filter out negative numbers:->

data = list(filter(lambda x: x>0, data))

Comment: @BhaveshRathod If you are using a lambda in filter then there is no reason to use filter in the first place. Just use a list comprehension: `[n for n in raw_data if n > 0]`

Comment: That's right @Lecdi.!